Field extension from adjoining matrix to $\mathbb{Q}$
Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and write $\chi_A \in \mathbb{Q}[T]$ for its characteristic polynomial. Suppose that $\chi_A$ is irreducible. Then, $\chi_A$ has $n$ distinct roots $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$. On the other hand, by Cayley-Hamilton, we also have that $\chi_A(A)=0$.
Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Q}[A, \alpha_1 I,..., \alpha_n I] \le M_n(\mathbb{C})$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and we identify $\mathbb{Q} \le R$ with $q \mapsto qI$. Then, $\chi_A$ has more roots in $R$ than its degree. Therefore, $R$ cannot be a field (unlike $\mathbb{Q}[A]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1 I,..., \alpha_n I]$). We further deduce that it cannot even be an integral domain, as a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space which is not a field.
Let $S = \mathbb{Q}[A, \alpha_1I]$. Can this be a field ($\iff$ integral domain)?
I think the answer is no. Suppose $S$ is a field. Then, $S$ extends to a splitting field $F$ for $\chi_A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (with exactly $n$ roots). If we start at $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1I]$ and follow the construction of the splitting field, then it seems that we can never get $A \in F$. But I'm not sure if this reasoning is entirely valid.

The first ring we need to understand here is $\mathbb{Q}[A]$. In general this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[t]/m_A(t)$ where $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial. If $\chi_A$ is irreducible then it agrees with the minimal polynomial, so in this case it's isomorphic to the field $K = \mathbb{Q}[t]/\chi_A(t)$ obtained by formally adjoining a root of the characteristic polynomial.
Next we need to understand the influence of adding in the scalar matrices $\alpha_1 I, \dots \alpha_n I$. Write $L = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_n] \subset \mathbb{C}$; this is a splitting field of $\chi_A(t)$. The effect of adding in these scalar matrices is that we have
$$R = L[A] \subset M_n(L),$$
the $L$-subalgebra of $M_n(L)$ generated by $A$. This means that $R$ is now isomorphic to $L[t]/(m_{A, L}(t))$ where $m_{A, L}$ is now the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $L$. But $\chi_A(t)$ just splits into distinct linear factors $\prod (t - \alpha_i)$ over $L$, by construction, so $\chi_A$ is still the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $L$. This means we have
$$R \cong L[t]/\chi_A(t) \cong L[t]/(\prod (t - \alpha_i)) \cong L^n$$
by the Chinese remainder theorem; in particular $R$ is not a field for $n \ge 2$. We can even describe all of the $n$ homomorphisms $R \to L$ given by the $n$ projections explicitly; namely, they act as the identity on $L$ and send $A \in L[A]$ to $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_n$ respectively.
The analysis of $S$ is similar. $K$ above is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1] \subset L$, and this time we have
$$S = K[A] \subset M_n(K),$$
the $K$-subalgebra of $M_n(K)$ generated by $A$. It is again true that $\chi_A$ is still the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $K$ (concretely, this is because we know $A$ has distinct eigenvalues over $L$) which means we have
$$S \cong K[t]/\chi_A(t) \cong K \times K[t]/p(t)$$
by the Chinese remainder theorem again, because we can write $\chi_A(t) = (t - \alpha_1) p(t)$ in $K[t]$. The first factor of $K$ corresponds to the factor of $t - \alpha_1$ while the second factor corresponds to the rest. It still follows that $S$ is not a field for $n \ge 2$. The projection $S \to K$ to the first factor is explicitly given by the map which sends both $A$ and $\alpha_1 I$ to $\alpha_1$, and its kernel contains $A - \alpha_1 I$ (in fact the kernel is exactly $(A - \alpha_1 I)$), which therefore cannot be invertible in $S$.
These arguments are confusing because there are multiple different objects running around which are all roots of $\chi_A(t)$ (namely, both $A$ and the roots $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$) so one has to be careful to distinguish them! Also it is not really necessary to embed anything into $\mathbb{C}$ here, you can just take $L$ to be a splitting field of $\chi_A$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]/\chi_A(\alpha)$.

Hi, Qiaochu. Thanks, yes, I meant to write $R,S \le M_n(\mathbb{C})$. I'm afraid I don't really follow most of the answer, including both pairs of claimed isomorphisms, and what exactly corresponds to the multiplication map $K \otimes K \to K$.

@J.S.: so, to be maximally concrete, write $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1] \subset \mathbb{C}$. There is a homomorphism $S \to K$ given by sending both $A$ and $\alpha_1 I$ to $\alpha_1$, and its kernel contains $A - \alpha_1 I$, which is nonzero. This means $S$ can't be a field. Here you may not be entirely convinced that this homomorphism is well-defined; the tensor product isomorphism above ensures this but you can probably write down a more concrete proof.

@J.S.: I've rewritten the answer to remove the use of tensor products.

Thanks, I really appreciate it. I was comfortable with the material on tensor products in Atiyah-Macdonald, but I guess not so much with working with them. As you say, $\mathbb{C}$ is not needed; I decided to use it for brevity. If I had one minor point, for the justification of the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $L$, in order to prove it is $\chi_A$, I think it is necessary to test on every eigenvector? I'm not sure otherwise how it follows by construction.

@J.S.: concretely, the minimal polynomial must still have every eigenvalue of $A$ as a root, and all the roots are distinct. But abstractly it is in fact the case that the minimal polynomial of a matrix is always invariant under extension of scalars (this is related to the tensor product calculation), and this is a nice exercise.

I see, thank you!

You can also simply observe that the (complex) eigenvalues of $A-\alpha_1I$ are $\alpha_i-\alpha_1$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$. As $0=\alpha_1-\alpha_1$ is one of the eigenvalues, it follows that $A-\alpha_1I$ cannot be invertible. Hence your ring cannot be a field.

Thanks for the answer. It's humbling how often a different perspective on a question makes it seem entirely trivial.
